# How to select even and odd intergers and get their totals

Tags: python

Ok im starting fresh and im going to bear everything I have exactly as it is.

NumbersMake.py

```
#This program writes 1 line of 12 random integers, each in the
#range from 1-100 to a text file.

def main():

    import random

    #Open a file named numbers.txt.
    outfile = open('numbers.txt', 'w')

    #Produce the numbers
    for count in range(12):
        #Get a random number.
        num = random.randint(1, 100)

        #Write 12 random intergers in the range of 1-100 on one line
        #to the file.
        outfile.write(str(num) + " ")

    #Close the file.
    outfile.close()
    print('Data written to numbers.txt')

#Call the main function
main()
```

---

The code above produces a text file that says:

60 90 75 94 54 12 10 45 60 92 47 65

The numbers above are 12 randomly generated integers sepearted by a space.

Would it be easier in the second script if I removed the spaces?

NumbersRead.py

```
#This program reads 12 random integers, outputs each number
#to its own line and then outputs the total of the even and odd  intergers.

def main():

    #Open a file named numbers.txt.
    infile = open('numbers.txt', 'r')

    #Read/process the file's contents.
    file_contents = infile.readline()
    numbers = file_contents.split(" ")
    odd = 0
    even = 0
    num = int(file_contents)
    for file_contents in numbers:
        if num%2 == 0:
            even += num
        else:
            odd += num

    #Close the file.
    infile.close()

    #Print out integer totals
    print('The total of the even intergers is: ', even)
    print('The total of the odd intergers is: ', odd)

#Call the main function
main()
```

---

The error I am receiving from the above script trying to process the total of the even and odd numbers is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "numbersread.py", line 29, in <module>
    main()
  File "numbersread.py", line 14, in main
    num = int(file_contents)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '60 90 75 94 54 12 10 45 60 92 47 65 '
```

I dont know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Might want to consider incrementing odd/even at some point...?

Comment: @Careugh: Is this how you have the file indented on your computer? Because the way it looks on my screen is indented incorrectly.

Comment: @Joshua Snider: Yes it is. The code above works withut any errors BUT it gives me the wrong answers in the output.

Comment: @Careugh `even = 0` and the `while` on the following line have different indentations, so it should be erroring.  Make sure everything is copied right

Comment: And it looks like several lines outside of the `while` should be inside it.

Comment: @Careugh: I think the same way as Izkata. Furthermore, most pythonistas put all of their import statements at the top of the file (but after comments). Although, you could delete that `import random` since it doesn't look like it's being used.

Answer (score 2):

Presuming you have a list like `["1","2","3"...]`

```
odd = sum(int(x) for x in  numbers if x % 2)
even = sum(int(x) for x in  numbers if not x % 2)
```

The best way is to use `with` to open your files and map to int first:

```
with open('numbers.txt') as f: # closes you files automatically
    numbers = map(int,f.read().split())


    odd = sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2) 
    even = sum(x for x in numbers if not x % 2)
```

If you had a very large file you would iterate over each line and sum as you go.

Also you only read a single line using `readline`, if you want only the first line replace `f.read().split()` with `f.readline().split()`

`sum(x for x in numbers if x % 2)` is a [generator expression](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), *Variables used in the generator expression are evaluated lazily when the **next**() method is called for generator object*

Comment: `sum_even == sum-sum_odd` is also handy

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "-", line 33, in <module>
    main()
  File "-", line 21, in main
    value = int(file_contents)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '60 90 75 94 54 12 10 45 60 92 47 65 '

Comment: @Careugh, add what your file actually looks like because if that is a line then you are not using my code

Comment: @Careugh, looking at your edit then it is impossible that you are getting an error using the code in my answer. I suggest you add the data exactly as it is in your text file

Answer (score 0):

This looks suspiciously like homework to me, but here's what I'd put in place of your while loop

```
for num_str in numbers:
  num = int(num_str)
  if num%2 == 0: #Even
    even += num
  else:
    odd += num
```

Comment: After converting my string to intergers it gives me this error using your code : ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '60 90 75 94 54 12 10 45 60 92 47 65 '

Comment: Are you sure you split it correctly then? It's saying that numbers contains a giant string '60 90 75 94 54 12 etc...'. If you put print(numbers) before this for loop, numbers should have it's value as something like ['60', '90', '75', ...]

Comment: Yes I would believe it would be a giant string. its 12 integers on 1 line with a space between them.

Comment: @Careugh: You can use split https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split to convert a giant strip of space seperated number-strings to a list of number-strings. For example '60 90 75'.split() = ['60', '90' ,'75'].